# Optimizing Query - I'm doing something very wrong here. Alternatives?

Tags: oracle11g, query-performance

So basically what this query does is SUM some value, and fetch some data from another table (with 1.8 million records - EDTF007 - the one in the WITH). EDTF011 (main table) has around 800k records.

So what's the problem?

Well... the field that I fetch from EDTF007 has some rules (seen in the CASE clause). I fetch the field CCONTA by making different "INNER JOINS" (as seen in the CASE).

The database cries for 1 hour to run this query. I've ran statistics, I've created indexes (rebuild them), tried access directly to the partitions. And it takes around 1 hour to run this query. Not acceptable at this moment.

The thing is... I'm out of ideas... and the problem is the structure of the query because... the WAIT events that I get... are all related to this bad query structure... :(

Any ideas how could I turn this around? An update on the table is also too slow I think...

```
WITH IMP AS (SELECT CCONTA, CREFERENCIA FROM EDTF007_IMPARIDADE  PARTITION (P_IMPARIDADE_201703))

SELECT  SUM(GC.MAVALIAA), 
V.ID, NVL(GC.CKNUMCTA, '00000000000'), NVL(GC.CKBALCAO, '0000'), GC.CKPRODUT, GC.CKSUBPRO, GC.ZDEPOSIT, GC.MSLDACT, SUM(GC.MAVALIAA), GC.TIPGARBL, GC.CGARANT, NVL(G.TIPO_GAR, 'SEM GAR'), G.TIPO_GAR2, GC.CREFERENCIA_IMP, 

 CASE
  WHEN (SUBSTR(GC.CKPRODUT, 1, 3) ) IN ('096' , '097' , '020' , '021' , '024') AND GC.CKPRODUT != 'MOR' THEN   
  (SELECT DISTINCT CCONTA FROM IMP WHERE (GC.CKBALCAO || GC.CKNUMCTA) = CCONTA)

  WHEN (SUBSTR(GC.CKPRODUT, 1, 3) ) IN ('035') AND GC.CKPRODUT != 'MOR' THEN  
  (SELECT DISTINCT CCONTA FROM IMP WHERE  GC.ZDEPOSIT = CREFERENCIA)

  WHEN NVL(GC.CKBALCAO  ||GC.CKNUMCTA, '000000000000000') IN (SELECT IMP.CCONTA FROM RE_ED.EDTF007_IMPARIDADE IMP  WHERE (IMP.PRODUTO ) = ( '000' )  AND (IMP.SEGMENTO ) IN ('IE' , 'IP' , 'IA' , 'GI')) AND GC.CKPRODUT != 'MOR' THEN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT CCONTA FROM IMP WHERE (GC.CKBALCAO || GC.CKNUMCTA) = CCONTA)

  WHEN SUBSTR(GC.CKPRODUT, 1, 3)  NOT IN ('096' , '097' , '020' , '021' , '024' , '035' ) AND GC.CKPRODUT != 'MOR' THEN
  (SELECT DISTINCT CCONTA FROM IMP WHERE (GC.CKBALCAO || GC.CKNUMCTA || GC.CREFERENCIA_IMP) = CCONTA || CREFERENCIA)  

  WHEN GC.CKPRODUT = 'MOR'  THEN  
  (SELECT DISTINCT CCONTA FROM IMP WHERE (GC.CKBALCAO || GC.CKNUMCTA || GC.CREFERENCIA_IMP) = CCONTA || CREFERENCIA)

  ELSE '000000000000000' 
END CCONTA_IMP,
GC.CREATED_BY, GC.CREATED_DATE 

FROM RE_ED.EDTD011_GARANTIAS_CONTRATO GC,
    (SELECT MAX(IDVERSAO) AS ID FROM RE_CD.CDTD009_VERSOES WHERE (TABELA) = ('RE_CD.CDTD015_GARANTIAS_CONTRATO')) V, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT TIPO_GAR, TIPO_GAR2, CODIGO FROM RE_CD.CDTD011_COD_GARANTIAS WHERE FLAG_ATIVO = 1 AND DTBEGIN_VER <= TO_TIMESTAMP(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2017-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM')) AND DTEND_VER >= TO_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2017-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))) G
WHERE (GC.ANO) = ('2017') 
            AND (GC.MES) = ('03') 
            AND (GC.CGARANT) = (G.CODIGO) 
GROUP BY V.ID, GC.CKNUMCTA, GC.CKBALCAO, GC.CKPRODUT, GC.CKSUBPRO, GC.ZDEPOSIT, GC.MSLDACT, GC.TIPGARBL, GC.CGARANT, G.TIPO_GAR, G.TIPO_GAR2, GC.CREFERENCIA_IMP, GC.CREATED_BY, GC.CREATED_DATE;
```

EDIT: After some conversation with a collegue he sugested to separate the query universe and instead of 1 query, I should try with 5 insert queries for each case. I'm going forward with this approach. Lets see how it goes. The main goal is a Insert into Select by the way.

Comment: I'm impressed you're not getting "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" with that case statement! If you're only expecting a single cconta value to be returned with each select from imp, why not skip the distinct and add `rownum = 1` to the where clause?

Comment: You are 100% right. EDTF007 table has a combined PK. If it returns more than 2 values for CCONTA... bam... my fault anyway.